# Can we select features by examining scatterplots?

Tags: self-study, feature-selection, scatterplot

Suppose, I have a data set with eight features in my hand. I want to find features to predict the diamonds, hearts, clubs, spades.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   f1   |   f2   |   f3    |   f4    |    f5    |   f6    |   f7    |  f8
+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------
|        |        |         |         |          |         |         |
```

`f1` column is for class-labels and the rest of them are features.

First, I have rendered a scatter plot by taking the features `f2` and `f3` and it looks like the following,

[image]

Later, I have rendered a scatter plot by taking the features `f3` and `f4` and it looks like the following,

[image]

in the 1st plot, `x` = `f2` and `y = f3`. In the 2nd plot, `x` = `f3` and `y` = `f4`.

If $Red$ = Diamonds, $Blue$ = Spades, $Magenta$ = Hearts, and $Black$ = Clubs,

**I have the following questions,**

**(1)** Why are some plots cohesive and others are not?

**(2)** What do these two plots tell about those four types of cards?

**(3)** Which two features, among `f2`, `f3`, and `f4`, would you choose for further experiment of pattern recognition and why?

Comment: Just to be clear, Are you trying to predict a variable with these 8 features and is that variable the value on the y axis?

Comment: What do the x and y axis represent?

Comment: Ok I get it, you want to find features to predict the diamonds, hearts, clubs, spades

Comment: Can you explain why visual inspection of features is of interest to you. As far as predicting labels go this should be a routine multi-variable classification problem.

Comment: @ArunJose A visual inspection can be extremely illuminating on *why* features classify the different cards the way they do.  If the goal is simple prediction, then it may not be useful.  But if one wishes to delve deeper into the causes, then plotting the data is a must.  In fact, in any statistical problem, plotting the data is a fantastic first step.

Comment: My problem actually wasn't with the objective of visual analysis but the intention of the OP behind this. As pointed out, this has to do with homework/ academic course work and the question does not expose any research on the OP's part. There is simply sharing of the data and three problem statements.

Comment: Free consultation is not what stack exchange is set up for. I was hoping you'd improve the quality of your question by first adding information about your current research. What conclusions have you drawn and ask if there are additional ways to supplement your work. Visual analysis is far from useless, never implied so in my comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems nobody is interested to answer my question rather than down-voting.

So, finally, I figured out the answers.

> (1) [Why are some plots cohesive and others are not?](http://access-excel.tips/excel-calculate-covariance-coefficient-of-correlation/)

Cohesive plots mean the features are correlated.

Scattered means features are not or least correlated.

> (2) What do these two plots tell about those four types of cards?

They don't actually tell anything about those card types. They just tell us about the degree of correlation they have in their features.

> (3) Which two features, among f2, f3, and f4, would you choose for further experiment of pattern recognition and why?

Although they don't make much difference, I would choose, 2 and 3.

Coz, the plot of 2 and 3 looks a somewhat more scattered than the plot of 3 and 4.

The answer could have been easier if we could have observed another plot of 2 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> Cohesive plots mean the features are correlated.
>
> Scattered means features are not or least correlated.

but actually, "scattered plot means features ar not or least correlated" is not always correct

AND

> Although they don't make much difference, I would choose, 2 and 3.
>
> Coz, the plot of 2 and 3 looks a somewhat more scattered than the plot
>   of 3 and 4.

but you should not choose relying only on those two plots.

Maybe you may want to run a separate regression analysis, for each shape, using all of the features as predictors. If the features are uncorrelated, you can see which is the feature that maximally represent each shape.

If you just want to look at the scatterplots, you should have a 4x8 matrix of plots, where you can look at the whole data. Then, visually, you can say which feature (of the eight) is *better correlated* with each shape (4).

Otherwise, I think that the answer is 'no, we can't select features ONLY by examining scatterplots'.

Comment: "but you should not choose relying only on those two plots.

Maybe you may want to run a separate regression analysis, for each shape, using all of the features as predictors. If the features are uncorrelated, you can see which is the feature that maximally represent each shape." --- Yes. I know. But, the question was about only on the observation of scatter plots. Nothing else.

Comment: Well, so I'd say that the answer is 'no'.